# Restrict characters in comment section

Tags: php, comments, sanitization, characters

I am using Travelify theme and I am having some trouble restricting the characters in the comment section (textarea) or where the name or mail goes into the input tags.

I read some articles about changing the core files from `wp-includes` like `post.php / post-formats.php / formatting.php` , for changing the `preg_match` function and only allow `a-zA-Z0-9` and some other like `.,?` characters or others to be used.And i would also like to add a text that appears that dosen't allow special characters.

I know that is not the best practice to change the core files, but some times it can help you.

Comment: Changing core files will always come back to haunt you. If you're concerned about sanitizing user input, read up on [Data Sanitization in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Answer (score 1):

Never edit the WordPress core files.

Instead you should hook into the [pre_comment_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_comment_content/), which is where the comment text from the textarea is being sanitized, before it's inserted into the database.

In the example below preg_replace is used to sanitize the comment text submitted. You should modify the function to fit your needs.

```
function keha_filter_comment( $comment_content ) {
    $comment_sanitized = preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", "", $comment_content );
    return $comment_sanitzed;
}
add_action( 'pre_comment_content', 'keha_filter_comment' );
```

There are also some other filter hooks available for the other comment fields available, you can find them within the [WordPress code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1666), look for the *apply_filters*, also listed below:

- pre_comment_author_name
- pre_comment_user_ip
- pre_comment_author_url
- pre_comment_author_email
- pre_comment_content

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, I added the code into `functions.php` from themes folder.Alltough it lets me send the comment with special characters like `!_^` and when i try to send it a second time it replies `Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that! `. I mention the fact that the first comment in the admin dashboard has no content....

Comment: You need to alter the regular expression, not my strongest skill, but I think somebody out there should know how to modify it for you.

Yes, you can not add the same comment twice. It's made this way by design, to avoid spam comments.

Comment: I found a JQuery plugin that does the work `jquery.alphanum` , it's pretty good and works for paste (ctrl + v) too.